# Excel - Using indirect function across sheets with user input

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have 2 sheets, in Sheet1 I have a user input cell (in **J6**) where the user types a column name from Sheet2 (for example "**CR**").

I want to have a cell in Sheet1 that is a specific cell from Sheet2, from the column which the user specified in Sheet1 (let's say **CR17**).

I guess what I'm trying to do is sort of like this:

```
=Sheet2!indirect(J6&17)
```

which doesn't work obviously.

I looked at the "indirect to another sheet" threads but they didn't really help, hope someone here can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following:

```
=indirect("Sheet2!"&J6&17)
```